# Google data studio: How to order a dimension?

Tags: visualization, google

I'd like to visualize the number of bookings per month, but I can't understand how to order the months (they are a dimension and not a metric, maybe that's the problem?).
When I try to do so it asks me the type of aggregation but I need no aggregation to do so. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Sort like this:

[image]

Hope this works, and I'm adding extra words to fulfill minimum character count.

Comment: I tried this way but it allows me to do so only with some kind of aggregation, but obviously I don't need aggregation! I'm confused

Comment: If you provide further information such as a screenshot, it would be easier to assist. Without that, please refer to 
 https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9320174?hl=en.

I assume aggregation is prompted due to multiple dimensions in your report.